# How can I paginate a Perl array?

Tags: arrays, perl

I don't know if the question  is clear or not, anyway, I am reading some data from my google drive spreadsheet using `Net::Google::Spreadsheet`, and i fetch all the rows in an array as follow `my @rows = $worksheet->rows`, however, I want to ... let say divide `@rows` between other arrays, for example `@rows` has 200 elements, i want to give the first 50 to `@array1` and the next 50 to `@array2` and so on without using a counter (`counter++; if (counter > 50) ...`). Or let say i just want to get the elements between 70 and 110 for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
my @array1 = @rows[0 .. 49];
my @array2 = @rows[50 .. 99];
```

This is referred to as data slicing. Refer to this [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) for more details.

Comment: @Leonardo Herrera, I had to wait 10minutes ^^

Answer (score 5):

The plain array slice answer is great. I just want to increase visibility of another (class/style of) solution, specifically [Data::Page](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Page).

> *It has been said before that this code is "too simple" for CPAN, but I must disagree.*

It can seem like overkill but it makes the stuff clean, predictable, and repeatable. When code starts to grow past the one-off stage, it can help quite a lot.

```
use strictures;
use Data::Page;

my @stuff = ( "a" .. "z" );

my $pager = Data::Page->new;
$pager->total_entries(scalar@stuff);
$pager->entries_per_page(6); # Arbitrary for demo, pick your own page size.

for my $p ( $pager->first_page .. $pager->last_page )
{
    $pager->current_page($p);
    for my $entry ( $pager->splice(\@stuff) )
    {
        print $entry, " is on page ", $pager->current_page, $/;
    }
}
__END__
a is on page 1
--snip--
z is on page 5
```

Comment: GREAT, Thanks @Ashley ^^, you gave me an idea for another thing.